# I get an undefine error in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe below:

```
<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe>
```

I am trying to stop a command below but I keep getting an undefined error:

```
$('.upload_target').contentwindow is undefined
```

How can I fix this undefined error?

Below is code:

```
   $(".uploadbutton").click(function() {
          $(".upload_target").contentWindow.stop(); //for anything but IE
          $(".upload_target").contentWindow.document.execCommand("Stop"); // for IE
  return stopImageUpload();
```

});

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get `undefined` because `contentWindow` is native Javascript and you're using it on a jQuery collection, which doesn't have `contentWindow` as a value. You have to get the original DOM object first. Do this instead:

```
$('.upload_target').get(0).contentWindow
```

Comment: Hi, I am not getting the error which is great but can I ask you one last question. the code above was to stop a file uploading but this did not seem to work. Do you know how to stop a file uploading by jquery when user clicks on the .uploadbutton?

Comment: @user1333290 we have no way of answering your second question without knowing what `uploadbutton` is.

Comment: .uploadbutton is a class given to a normal button (input type='button class='uploadbutton')