# iframe contentWindow undefined even after .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to set the height of the `iframe` match it's content. But `iframe.contentWindow` returns `undefined` even after putting it inside `.load()`. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myIFrame = $('#iframe');
    console.log(myIFrame.contentWindow); //getting undefined
});
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong in this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: After `var inst = this.handle` in `setAutoHeight`, Could you try `console.log(inst)`?

Comment: `console.log(inst)` isn't printing anything. `alert(inst)` is getting `[object Object]` @YonggooNoh

Comment: I think you should check the `inst` in debugging mode.

Comment: In debugging mode, `console.log(inst)` is printing `Object [ iframe#iframe-main ]`. I guess the `.load` function is firing off before the `iframe` actual loading because the `alert(doc)` displays `undefined` before there's any visible content of the `iframe`. @YonggooNoh

Comment: `load` event will be fired when the iframe contents is **actually** loaded. Could you give me a sample JSFiddle page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so `contentWindow` is native Javascript and since I'm using jQuery, I'll have to get the original DOM object first. The correct way to get `contentWindow` :

```
var win = $('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow;
```

[For More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167460/i-get-an-undefine-error-in-iframe)